# Why does the change of html of a button and redirect not work on iphone?

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, safari

I have tried the following code with numerous browsers and it does not work on iphone with safari, but it does work on google chrome for iphone.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.top-link-checkout').attr('href',checkout_url);
    $(".button.btn-cart.btn-prod").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cart_url = $('.top-link-cart').attr('href');
            $(".button.btn-cart.btn-prod").html('<span><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x add-to-cart-icon"></i>Adding...</span>',
            function(){
                window.location.href = cart_url;
            });
    });
});
```

On iphone with safari it just goes to the url without changing the html.

Any ideas how I can make it work on iphone with safari.

*Update*

Changed the code suggested by: @rory-mccrossan to add a timeout:

```
$('.top-link-checkout').attr('href',checkout_url);
    $(".button.btn-cart.btn-prod").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cart_url = $('.top-link-cart').attr('href');
            $(".button.btn-cart.btn-prod").html('<span><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x add-to-cart-icon"></i>Adding...</span>');
            setTimeout(gotocart, 100);
    });
    function gotocart(){
        window.location.href = cart_url;
    };
```

Still doesn't work on iphone safari.

Comment: Given that `html()` has no second parameter, I'm not sure how this is working at all. Either way, you're redirecting as soon as the click happens. I would assume that the renderer of Safari iOS doesn't update the UI after it discovers a HTTP request has been made. A `setTimeout()` may help, although is rather hacky.

Comment: It has a second parameter...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/ Nope, it has a getter, or 2 setters that take a single string or function respectively.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp. Please explain why you think `I'm not sure how this is working at all`. Alright so I have to use a setTimeout().

Comment: Not all jQuery functions have a callback - only those which operate on a queue or are asynchronous. `html()` is neither. Also, I wouldn't ever refer to anything W3Schools says as fact: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated question. Hmmm still not working. Can you think of anything else?

Answer (score 0):

does the button exists? or is it loaded later per ajax or so. 
you can try to set the click event on the body and trigger the button then.
like:

```
$("body").on('click', ".button.btn-cart.btn-prod", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var cart_url = $('.top-link-cart').attr('href');
        $(".button.btn-cart.btn-prod").html('<span><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x add-to-cart-icon"></i>Adding...</span>',
        function(){
            window.location.href = cart_url;
        });
});
```

also it maybe helps to put the function in a document ready function.

greetings timmi